# Any ideas why I am getting "yum" is not a valid attribute for a play?

Tags: ansible, syntax, yaml

I have the following and when I do a syntax check just on this part it is saying that "yum" is not a valid attribute for the play:

```yaml
---
# tasks files for ansible-vsftpd
-  name: Packages are installed
   yum:
     name: "{{ vsftpd_package }}"
     state: present
```

if I run a syntax check just on this part or at the end of the rest of the code, it keeps coming back that "yum" is not a valid attribute for play and is flagging line 3 of the code.

Any ideas?

Comment: what version of Ansible are you using? looking at the [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/yum_module.html), yum is only available for Python 2; if python 3 is in place, you'll need to use [dnf](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/dnf_module.html#ansible-collections-ansible-builtin-dnf-module)

Comment: You are using a task file as if it was a playbook.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax error message

```
 "<moduleName>" is not a valid attribute for the play
```

is because of there seems to be something missing for a valid playbook. In example the keywords `hosts` and `tasks` are missing.

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost

  tasks:

  -  name: Packages are installed
     yum:
       name: "{{ vsftpd_package }}"
       state: present
```

**Documentation**

- [Playbook syntax](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_intro.html#playbook-syntax)